# Phonegap/Cordova plugins are not being fired

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

After updating my phonegap project I'm having some weird issue with the plugins, before they worked fine after the update the plugins are not being fired at the first time, the strange this is when I close the app (foreground) and open the again the plugins load. In my case the 'navigator.notification' and the camera.

Did anyone have this issue? or know someone I could do to avoid this to happen?

*I'm testing on IOS

Cheers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried reinstalling the plugins with `cordova remove [plugin]` followed by `cordova add [plugin]`? I know that sounds like a bit of voodoo, but sometimes it will clear up mysterious plugin issues.

Comment: @sherb, I tried to do that, but it's still not working. if I run the app on the Cordova App,  the plugins work but if I install on my phone my application it stop working as they are expected. :/